# Unable to save changes in database with ruby instance method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I encountered an issue with a Ruby instance method. There is an instance of a Class Building with several parameters and I need to write a method that would change one of its parameters (Building_level). In terms of what to change the task is more or less clear. The code itself works fine in Ruby console, but when I try to use this code within a method, it fails to save any changes.

In other words, when I do this in console:

```
var = Building.first
var.some_id = 1
var.save
```

It works and changes are saved in the db. But when I use the same code inside a method (it is contained in Model) in console:

The method looks as follows:

```
def some_method
    some_id = 1
    self.save
end
```

```
var = Building.first
var.some_method
```

The changes are no there and var remains intact.

I couldn't find any explanation as to why it fails.

Answer (score 2):

You need `self.some_id = 1` in the method otherwise ruby parser treats `some_id` as a new local variable:

```
def some_method
    self.some_id = 1
    self.save
end
```

Interestingly, because `save` is not an "assignment method" you can call it without the `self.` if you want.

It does not look like you are actually assign the id value to the record anywhere before saving it.